# Sockets in C# (Client) <-> Ruby (Server)

Tags: c#, ruby, sockets

I'm serious doubts about sockets. Not on sockets in a language in particular, but on sockets between Ruby (pure) and C # (Unity 5.0.4 ~ Mono).

I'm trying to do a job for college, where I have to pass information between the graphics engine and my server. But now I'm stuck in C#!

How do I, my dear code in C #, connect to my server in Ruby? I tried that way, but it still fails.

Ruby Server

```
#####################
# HelmTek Serv v001 #
#####################
require "socket"                                                                    
#####################
# Funções e Métodos #
#####################
def TCPService()                                                
    server = TCPServer.open(8080)
    puts("Serv started on 8080")
    loop{
    Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
        puts ("New Client") 
        client.puts(Time.now.ctime)
        printf("Enviado a data")
        client.puts "Closing the connection. Bye!"  
        line = client.recv(100)
                puts line.to_s
        client.close
    end
    }
end
def UDPService()
    loop{
    }
end
#####################
# Algoritmo do Serv #
#####################
puts "HelmTek Server 2015"                                                 
puts "por Marlon H. Schweigert"
Thread.new {TCPService()}                                   
UDPService()
```

C# Client

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public class SocketConnector : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient ("localhost", 8080);

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (client.GetStream ());
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter (client.GetStream ());

        sw.WriteLine ("Ola");
        sw.Flush ();

        while (true){
            string linha = sr.ReadLine();
            if (linha == null) break;
            Debug.Log (linha);
        }

        client.Close ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know what is your error, I can only show my source which it works...

```
bool isConnect = false;

void ConnectAndRead(){  //Instead of Start(), I use this to control the connection
  using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient() ){
    client.Connect(your_ip, your_port);
    if (!client.Connected) throw new Exception();
    isConnect = true;
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (stream );
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter (stream );
    sw.AutoFlush = true;
    while (true) {
        //I copy your source and paste here!!
        string linha = sr.ReadLine();
        if (linha == null) break;
        Debug.Log (linha);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: After searching a lot, I tried to run my server on a virtual machine (Ubuntu) and my client on my PC (Windows 10). Since then usually they talked to the same codes!
Apparently it was the Antivirus or Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot, I tried to run my server on a virtual machine (Ubuntu) and my client on my PC (Windows 10). Since then usually they talked to the same codes!
Apparently it was the Antivirus or Firewall.